# feel + ... + to-infinitive / bare infinitive

Tags: bare-infinitive, catenative-verbs

> **(1)** feel + ... + to-infinitive: *She felt his answer **to be** evasive*.
>
> **(2)** feel + ... + bare infinitive: *She felt him **keep** something back*.

I have been trying to find the rule: when "*feel*" must be used with to-infinitives and when with bare infinitives. Do you know it?

The only one I could find: we must use "*to*" only before "*be*", and before all other verbs we cannot use "*to*". Is it right?

Thanks!